# Issue in Model-View-Controller Pattern implementation

Tags: python, design-patterns

I am running an example for learning The Model-View-Controller Pattern in python, but the code is giving an error. I tried to debug the code, but I couldn't find the main root/cause. Removing `close` connection system works, but what is the issue of the code? Can you advise me what is wrong?

```
# Filename: mvc.py 
import sqlite3 
import types 


class DefectModel: 
    def getDefectList(self, component): 
        query = '''select ID from defects where Component = '%s' ''' %component 
        defectlist = self._dbselect(query) 
        list = [] 
        for row in defectlist: 
            list.append(row[0])
            return list 

    def getSummary(self, id): 
        query = '''select summary from defects where ID = '%d' ''' % id 
        summary = self._dbselect(query) 
        for row in summary: 
            return row[0] 

    def _dbselect(self, query): 
        connection = sqlite3.connect('example.db') 
        cursorObj = connection.cursor() 
        results = cursorObj.execute(query) 
        connection.commit()
        cursorObj.close() 
        return results 

class DefectView: 
    def summary(self, summary, defectid): 
        print("#### Defect Summary for defect# %d ####\n %s"  % (defectid,summary) )

    def defectList(self, list, category): 
        print("#### Defect List for %s ####\n" % category )
        for defect in list: 
            print(defect )

class Controller: 
    def __init__(self): pass 

    def getDefectSummary(self, defectid): 
        model = DefectModel() 
        view = DefectView() 
        summary_data = model.getSummary(defectid) 
        return view.summary(summary_data, defectid) 

    def getDefectList(self, component): 
        model = DefectModel() 
        view = DefectView() 
        defectlist_data = model.getDefectList(component) 
        return view.defectList(defectlist_data, component)
```

This is related run.py.

```
#run.py
import mvc 
controller = mvc.Controller()
 # Displaying Summary for defect id # 2
print(controller.getDefectSummary(2)) 
# Displaying defect list for 'ABC' Component print 
controller.getDefectList('ABC')
```

If you need to create the database, it is available here:

```
# Filename: datbase.py 
import sqlite3 
import types 
# Create a database in RAM
db = sqlite3.connect('example.db')

# Get a cursor object
cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("drop table defects")

    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE defects(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Component TEXT, Summary TEXT)")

   cursor.execute("INSERT INTO defects VALUES (1,'XYZ','File doesn‘t get deleted')")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO defects VALUES (2,'XYZ','Registry doesn‘t get created')")
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO defects VALUES (3,'ABC','Wrong title gets displayed')")

    # Save (commit) the changes
    db.commit()

# We can also close the connection if we are done with it.
# Just be sure any changes have been committed or they will be lost.
db.close()
```

My error is as below:

```
> Windows PowerShell Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights
> reserved.
> 
> PS E:\Projects\test> & python e:/Projects/test/mvc.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "e:/Projects/test/mvc.py", line 56, in <module>
>     import mvc   File "e:\Projects\test\mvc.py", line 65, in <module>
>     cursor.execute("drop table defects") sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: defects PS E:\Projects\test> & python
> e:/Projects/ramin/mvc.py Traceback (most recent call last):  
> File "e:/Projects/test/mvc.py", line 56, in <module>
>     import mvc   File "e:\Projects\test\mvc.py", line 80, in <module>
>     print(controller.getDefectSummary(2))   File "e:\Projects\test\mvc.py", line 44, in getDefectSummary
>     summary_data = model.getSummary(defectid)   File "e:\Projects\test\mvc.py", line 18, in getSummary
>     for row in summary: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor. PS E:\Projects\test>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that the problem is this line: `cursor.execute("drop table defects")`

Maybe you dropped that table in a previous run, and since it's no longer there, sqlite3 raises an `OperationalError` exception.

In your code there is a comment that says that you are using an in-memory sqlite database, but you are not. This is how you create an in-memory db:

`db = sqlite3.connect(:memory:)`

If you use an in-memory db you don't need to drop anything, since you are creating the db on the fly when you run your script.

*Note*: last year I wanted to understand the MVC better, so I wrote a series of articles about it. [Here](https://www.giacomodebidda.com/mvc-pattern-in-python-sqlite) is the one where I use SQLite as a storage backend for my Model.

Comment: I am sorry, leave the part related to create the database, because for testing I created that part. I just run it once and there is no issue in that part. Problem is happening here:
in getDefectSummary
>     summary_data = model.getSummary(defectid)   File "e:\Projects\test\mvc.py", line 18, in getSummary
>     for row in summary: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Cannot operate on a closed cursor. PS E:\Projects\test>

Comment: Link is broken  :( : https://www.giacomodebidda.com/blog/mvc-pattern-in-python-dataset/

Comment: I read your code, I am not sure why u just close the connection at the end, after doing select, insert, update and delete? shouldn't we close the connection after each work? I think my problem is that part.however on that case in model-view-controller pattern it is a bit funny to close the connection after I finish my work... what if application crash and you cannot close your connection at all? it just creates junk object in the memory.